# How to index in a column based on the unique values in another column

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataset DF, which includes two columns of USER and DATETIME (column index is not in my data. It is what the output should look like). The rows in DF shows the activity in each minute. What I want is to create and fill a column called “index”. This index is to show the activities of equal to or less than 4 minutes. In other words, if the difference between DATETIME of row i and its following row i+1 is less than or equal to 4 minutes, they are in the same index (namely, in the same activity). But, if this difference is greater than 4 minutes, the next row (i+1) goes to the next activity and so on. Here is important. **I do not need** a code for the difference between DATETIMES. I have it here. What I want is a for loop that indexes the activities for each unique USER. Then, for the next USER, it should start from 1.  This is what I have tried. But I need a for in for loop or unique function. The output should look like the column “index”. Thanks for your help.

[image]

```
suum <- 1
DF$index[1] <- 1 

for (k in unique(DF$USER))

   {

  for (i in 2:(nrow(DF)))
   {
   if(as.numeric(difftime(ymd_hms(DF$DATETIME[i]), ymd_hms(DF$DATETIME[i-1]), units = "mins") <= 4)) 
      { DF$index[i] <- suum }

 else if(as.numeric(difftime(ymd_hms(DF$DATETIME[i]), ymd_hms(DF$DATETIME[i-1]),units = "mins") > 4))
    {DF$index[i] <- suum + 1}
    suum <- as.numeric(DF$index[i])
    } 

      }
```

Thanks to @Paul van Oppen for bringing my data in the format of R

```
data <- tibble(USER = c(rep(41, 10), rep(61, 6)),
DATETIME = as.POSIXct(c("2019/06/02 20:44:00", # 41
                      "2019/06/03 16:46:00", 
                      "2019/06/03 16:50:00", 
                      "2019/06/03 20:43:00", 
                      "2019/06/03 20:44:00", 
                      "2019/06/03 21:45:00", 
                      "2019/06/03 21:47:00", 
                      "2019/06/04 13:29:00", 
                      "2019/06/04 13:30:00",
                      "2019/06/04 13:37:00",
                      "2019/06/02 10:34:00", # 61
                      "2019/06/02 11:41:00",
                      "2019/06/02 11:59:00",
                      "2019/06/02 12:00:00",
                      "2019/06/02 14:12:00",
                      "2019/06/02 14:13:00"), 
                        "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")

                             )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this do it?

First make the data object (recommend to use a proper date time format such as `POSIXct` for your `DATETIME` column):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

data <- tibble(
  USER = c(rep(41, 10), rep(61, 6)),
  DATETIME = as.POSIXct(c("2019/06/02 20:44:00", # 41
                          "2019/06/03 16:46:00", 
                          "2019/06/03 16:50:00", 
                          "2019/06/03 20:43:00", 
                          "2019/06/03 20:44:00", 
                          "2019/06/03 21:45:00", 
                          "2019/06/03 21:47:00", 
                          "2019/06/04 13:29:00", 
                          "2019/06/04 13:30:00",
                          "2019/06/04 13:37:00",
                          "2019/06/02 10:34:00", # 61
                          "2019/06/02 11:41:00",
                          "2019/06/02 11:59:00",
                          "2019/06/02 12:00:00",
                          "2019/06/02 14:12:00",
                          "2019/06/02 14:13:00"), 
                            "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")

)
```

Then I use the `lag` function to calculate the time difference with the previous line and an `ifelse` to create a `marker` column which highlights those rows where the time difference in minutes is larger than 4. The `cumsum + 1` of the marker column should be the index you are after. Grouping by `USER` allows us to do the calculations by group. Finally, we get rid of the intermediate column `marker`.

```
data <- data %>%
  group_by(USER) %>%
  mutate(diff_time = DATETIME - lag(DATETIME, 1)) %>%
  mutate(marker = ifelse(as.numeric(diff_time > 4), 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(marker = replace_na(marker, 0)) %>%
  mutate(index = cumsum(marker) + 1) %>%
  select(USER, DATETIME, index)

> data
# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   USER [2]
    USER DATETIME            index
   <dbl> <dttm>              <dbl>
 1    41 2019-06-02 20:44:00     1
 2    41 2019-06-03 16:46:00     2
 3    41 2019-06-03 16:50:00     2
 4    41 2019-06-03 20:43:00     3
 5    41 2019-06-03 20:44:00     3
 6    41 2019-06-03 21:45:00     4
 7    41 2019-06-03 21:47:00     4
 8    41 2019-06-04 13:29:00     5
 9    41 2019-06-04 13:30:00     5
10    41 2019-06-04 13:37:00     6
11    61 2019-06-02 10:34:00     1
12    61 2019-06-02 11:41:00     2
13    61 2019-06-02 11:59:00     3
14    61 2019-06-02 12:00:00     3
15    61 2019-06-02 14:12:00     4
16    61 2019-06-02 14:13:00     4
```

Comment: Thanks, @Paul van Oppen. I ran your code. It creates the index column and inserts the values. But, in the index column, the row after the last row of USER 41, the index does not start from 1. It continues. I have brought the output here.

Comment: structure(list(USER = c(41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 
61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61), DATETIME = structure(c(1559508240, 1559580360, 
1559580600, 1559594580, 1559594640, 1559598300, 1559598420, 1559654940, 
1559655000, 1559655420, 1559471640, 1559475660, 1559476740, 1559476800, 
1559484720, 1559484780), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    index = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9)), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(
    USER = c(41, 61), .rows = list(1:10, 11:16)),

Comment: continue:  row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))

Comment: This will only happen if you did not include `group_by(USER)`. The grouping by `USER` should force the calculations to be done for each group.  Can you check?

Comment: No, @Paul van Oppen, It does not work although I use the group_by(USER)

Comment: Not sure then; the output on my PC clearly shows that the count restarts for the next group. I can recreate what you observe by removing the `group_by` function call.

Comment: Can you check if you have loaded `plyr` in addition to or instead of `dplyr`? If you do that the problem you flag occurs as well. Do a search for instance for `dplyr group_by not working if plyr is loaded` will give you several useful references.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, that last night I noticed that plyr package would deter the dplyr package from its functions.

Answer (score 4):

With `dplyr`, no loops needed:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(USER) %>%
  mutate(
    INDEX = cumsum(
      c(1, difftime((DATETIME), lag(ymd_hms(DATETIME), 1), units = "mins")[-1] > 4)
    )
  )
# # A tibble: 16 x 3
# # Groups:   USER [2]
#     USER DATETIME            INDEX
#    <dbl> <dttm>              <dbl>
#  1    41 2019-06-02 20:44:00     1
#  2    41 2019-06-03 16:46:00     2
#  3    41 2019-06-03 16:50:00     2
#  4    41 2019-06-03 20:43:00     3
#  5    41 2019-06-03 20:44:00     3
#  6    41 2019-06-03 21:45:00     4
#  7    41 2019-06-03 21:47:00     4
#  8    41 2019-06-04 13:29:00     5
#  9    41 2019-06-04 13:30:00     5
# 10    41 2019-06-04 13:37:00     6
# 11    61 2019-06-02 10:34:00     1
# 12    61 2019-06-02 11:41:00     2
# ...
```

(Untested, of course, since I can't import your picture of data. If you share data in valid R syntax, e.g. `dput(DF[1:20, ])`, I'll happily test and debug.)

Comment: `ymd_hms` returns a `POSIXct` class object, which is stored as a number of seconds. `?diff.POSIXt` doesn't explicitly mention units, but it does state that it is equivalent to recursively using subtraction. Subtraction applied to `POSIXct` objects returns the difference in seconds, AFAIK.

Comment: You'd need `diff(c(t1, t1 - 10))` - a second argument to diff is the lag amount. You're certainly right about the inconsistent units, though. I'll update my answer to use `difftime`.

Comment: Dear @Gregor Thomas, thanks a lot. I tried your code. it did not make a new variable (index).

Comment: I put the `lag` on the wrong one - updated now, with demo on the sample data.